# Apache ingores one vhost, others are loaded successfuly

Tags: debian, apache2, reverse-proxy

I have an app running on my debian server at port 4200 and 4201 and i am trying to make a reverse proxy for it in apache2 so it can work on domain my-domain.cz

I read almost all questions here about this topic but nothing solves my problem.

This is what 100-domain.cz.vhost in sites-enabled looks like:

```
<VirtualHost server-ip:80>
    ServerName domain.cz

    ProxyPass /  "http://anotherdomain.cz:4200/"
    ProxyPassReverse /  "http://anotherdomain.cz:4200/"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost server-ip:80>
    ServerName admin.domain.cz

    ProxyPass /  "http://anotherdomain.cz:4201/"
    ProxyPassReverse /  "http://anotherdomain.cz:4201/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Seems to be ok, because when i run apache2ctl -S it shows me:

```
server-ip:80       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domain.cz (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-domain.cz.vhost:1)
         port 80 namevhost domain.cz (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-domain.cz.vhost:1)
         port 80 namevhost admin.domain.cz (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-domain.cz.vhost:9)
```

When I came to the domain, it shows me totaly different vhost (api.domain.cz) which has another vhost after this one, but has ServerName only api.domain.cz - so it's matched (probably from my observation) because the vhost with reverse proxy is not even loaded (I tried to comment reverse proxy and make an existing document root but it doesnt work either).

Edit: All proxy apache modules are loaded - i checked it via apache2ctl -M and also tried to add LoadModule to the very beginning of vhost file

I would be happy for any advice,
David.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's because vhosts are loaded in order and the first one has the highest priority. So you need to specify and load them in reverse order (i.e. `api.domain.cz` before `domain.cz`).

> Name-based vhost If the entry corresponds to a name-based vhost the
>   name list contains one or more vhost structures. This list contains
>   the vhosts in the same order as the VirtualHost directives appear in
>   the config file.
>
> The first vhost on this list (the first vhost in the config file with
>   the specified IP address) has the highest priority and catches any
>   request to an unknown server name or a request without a Host: header
>   -- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/details.html#hostmatching
>   field.